# java calling method with string parameters

Tags: java, methods, static-methods

Beginner question here. This method should read a line from a text file, remove white space (and do some other stuff) and print the line to another file. However, when I call:

```
noWhiteSpace(words.txt, clean.txt);
```

it does not read the contents of the file. It merely writes the name of the input file to the new output file: i.e "clean.txt" contains the string "words.txt" and nothing else. I'm perplexed.

```
public static void noWhiteSpace(String inputFileName, String outputFileName) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(inputFileName);
    PrintStream outFile = new PrintStream(outputFileName);

    while (inFile.hasNext()) {        
        String line = inFile.nextLine(); // read a line
        line = line.trim();              // eliminate the white space
        outputFile.println(line);        // print line to output file
    }
}
```

Comment: If your file is not too large, you can make your life easier with FileUtils.readLines and FileUtils.writeLines

Comment: How about `new Scanner(new File(inputFileName))`?

Comment: Yup as per @cwschmidt and other answers use scanner.
you are just passing the String and not the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor for `Scanner` that takes a `String` parameter does not do what you think it does.  I think you want something like:

```
File file = new File(inputFileName);
try {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        // the rest of your code here
    }
    sc.close();
} 
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Read the javadoc on the [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) API.

```
/* Constructs a new Scanner that produces values scanned from the specified string.
Parameters:
source - A string to scan 
*/
public Scanner(String source)
```

Comment: If this answered your question, consider 'accepting' it, for future users.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a File instance to the Scanner instance and not the file name.

File file = new File("path/to/file/on/disk");
Scanner inFile = new Scanner(file);

Then read from the scanner, like inFile.nextLine() etc.